# Column alignment in DT datatable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

In my `shiny` app I am using `datatable` function from `DT` library to construct a table and want to align columns on center. I can use `formatStyle('column', textAlign = 'center')` but it affects only column body and not the header.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

We have to set `columnDefs` in the argument `option` of the function `datatable`.

See example below:

```
library(DT)

datatable(head(iris),
          rownames = FALSE,
          options = list(
            columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = 0:4))
            )
          )
```

We have to set the target. In the example all the 5 columns are aligned to "center" (`targets = 0:4`).

Finally, note that column numbers start from 0, not from 1.

**Note:** we can use `targets="_all"` to apply to all columns regardless of number of columns.

Comment: Is there any way to alignt cell contents vertically?I am trying to reproduce [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51973434/16936515) using fluidPage instead of fluidRow layout. When I replace fluidRow with fluidPage text and checkboxes in table do not layout vertically.