# How to put entire datatable onto html report? (or at least left align)

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, datatables-1.10

I have several wide tables that should fit onto an html report, but I don't know how to do it.

Consider the following example. It's rather silly I know, because I could chop the digits off, but many of my tables have string columns that are about this long and cannot be chopped:

````
---
title: "DT Fitting"
output: html_document
---

```{r testTable, fig.align = 'left', fig.width = 6in}
DT::datatable(datasets::euro.cross)
```
````

It renders an html report that looks like this:

[image]

Notice that I've tried using fig.align and fig.width to align or shrink the table, but they don't seem to work. Does anyone know to put this single table onto the page so as to be completely visible?

Comment: How about this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35752537/5645311

Comment: That centers the objects in the table, but not the table itself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a previous [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385696/how-to-adjust-the-output-width-of-rstudio-markdown-output-to-html) captures this.

This allows you to set the width via options(width = some number). This doesn't seem to be the ideal solution if you have multiple wide tables.

Another option is to consider, fixing the columns when setting up the datatables and enabling scrolling. Check out [Section 5](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html). They allow you to fix the first and last column, and scroll the columns in between.

Based on the Datatables link:

````
```{r}
      DT::datatable(datasets::euro.cross,
          extensions = 'FixedColumns',
             options = list(
                      dom = 't',
                      scrollX = TRUE,
                      fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 2, rightColumns = 1))
                    )
```
````